# Get innerHtml or innerText or nodeValue and exclude nested child?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to save my DOM into some JSON format and one key in the tree is `content`. This code works 'fine', but only for simple cases. I'm using now `nodeValue` to grab the text only from the first child, and it gives me good results, but it's breaking when the structure contains elements like `br`.

```
const uploadDom = (node, path, siblingsLeft, order) => {
  for (let item of node) {
    order = order + 1;
    database.ref("dom/" + path + "/" + order).update({
      id: item.id,
      type: item.tagName,
      class: item.className,
      content: item.childNodes[0].nodeValue
    });
    if (item.children.length) {
      siblingsLeft = item.children.length - 1;
      path = path + order + `/`;
      uploadDom(item.children, path, siblingsLeft, order);
    }
    if (siblingsLeft > 1) {
      a = order + "/";
      path = path.replace(a, "");
      siblingsLeft = 1;
    }
  }
};
```

Here is example HTML structure: (please note this structure is always dynamic)

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- wrapper has no text content so I want content value of null -->
   <p>I want to save this text as content value of P tag</p>
   <div class="wrapper-2">
   <!-- wrapper has no text content so I want content value of null -->
      <p>This P contains <br> new line element</p>
      <!-- I'm using nodeValue of first child so content will be = 'This P contains' -->
      <!-- content should be = 'This P contains <br> new line element' -->
      <p>I want to save this text as content value of P tag</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out smarter way to save my DOM tree, although I'm struggling with the way I can save text content as in the example above.

Comment: what is the purpose of transforming html (in general, not only for extract some values) into some json? why not use html directly?

Comment: I'm reformating this DOM structure inside database, and re-rendering it with modifications elsewhere, or just partially. I've found it the most efficient way, because the whole DOM is too large object. Also I'm applying styles inline, based on className and I don't want to save all inline styles in database.

Comment: so you can write your DOM as string directly (by innerHTML) - and save that string in DB - this is the cheapest way

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski thanks a lot for your comment. Another issue with saving the whole DOM is that multiple people can't work on it simultaneously. Right now I'm thinking about innerHtml again, and I think I can process these strings to get what I need. It might take lot's of traversing tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your DOM tree into valid json as follows

```js
let json = JSON.stringify(wrapper.innerHTML)

console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- wrapper has no text content so I want content value of null -->
   <p>I want to save this text as content value of P tag</p>
   <div class="wrapper-2">
   <!-- wrapper has no text content so I want content value of null -->
      <p>This P contains <br> new line element</p>
      <!-- I'm using nodeValue of first child so content will be = 'This P contains' -->
      <!-- content should be = 'This P contains <br> new line element' -->
      <p>I want to save this text as content value of P tag</p>
   </div>
</div>
```